# How use SQL IN() in Yii query builder

Tags: php, yii

i want to perform below query with Yii query builder

$sql = "select * from user where userid in (1,2,3,)"

pls help ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need as below

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('*')->from('user')->where(array('in', 'userid', array(1, 2,3)))->queryAll();
```